# awk command on a remote host, in Perl's system, does not work

Tags: perl, awk, ssh

I am writing a small Perl script that executes an Awk command :

I try to swap two columns in a file, the file is like this :

```
domain1,ip1
domain2,ip2
domain3,ip3
```

the result should be

```
ip1,domain1
ip2,domain2
ip3,domain3
```

The Perl command invoking awk is like this:

```
system("ssh -p 22 root\@$mainip 'awk -F, '{print $2,$1}' OFS=, /root/archive/ipdomain.txt > /root/ipdom.txt'");
```

This is the error I get :

```
awk: cmd. line:1: {print
awk: cmd. line:1:       ^ unexpected newline or end of string
```

any suggestions, please?

Comment: If you're doing it in Perl, you could have used `Net::OpenSSH` to connect to the remote machine and parse the file. This everything can be done using Perl instead shelling out the result.

Comment: The thing in your system() call isn't an awk command, it's a shell script. Sure awk is one of the tools called from that shell script but so is ssh and both will be called from the subshell created by `system()` (assuming perl's system() works the same way as awk's does).

Answer (score 1):

With the layered commands and all that multi-level quoting and escaping that need be done right,<sup>†</sup> no wonder it fails. A complex command like that will always be tricky, but libraries help a lot.

A properly quoted string to run through a shell can be formed with [String::ShellQuote](https://metacpan.org/pod/String::ShellQuote) <sup>‡</sup>

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use String::ShellQuote qw(shell_quote);

die "Usage: $0 file outfile\n" if @ARGV != 2;

my ($file, $out) = @ARGV;

my @cmd_words = 
    ( 'ssh', 'hostname', 'awk', q('{print $2 $1}'), $file, '>', $out );

my $cmd = shell_quote @cmd_words;

system($cmd);
```

Note how the [q() operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators) from of single quotes enables us to pass single quotes nicely.

This swaps the first two words on each line of a file and prints them, using `awk`, and redirects the output to a file, on a remote host. It works as expected in my tests (with a real hostname). Please adjust as needed.

Another possible improvement would be to use a library for `ssh`, like [Net::OpenSSH](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH).

A complete command, as the one in the question, to use in the above program

```
my @cmd_words = (
    'ssh', '-p', '22', "root\@$mainip", 
    'awk', '-F,', q('{print $2,$1}'), 'OFS=,', $file, '>', $out );
```

Tested with a file from the question.

---

The [makeVoiceBot answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73316632/4653379) is informative and it got half way there but I find the need for

```
system("ssh hostname \"awk '{print \\\$2 \\\$1}' $path\"");
```

This works in my tests (on systems I `ssh` to).  I try to avoid needing to deal with such quoting and escaping.

---

<sup>†</sup> This is a shell command which runs `ssh`, and then executes a command on the remote system which runs a shell (there) as well, in order to run `awk` and redirect its output to a file.

A bit more than an "*awk command*" as the title says.

---

<sup>‡</sup>  The library can prepare a command for bash (as of this writing), but one can look at the source for it and adjust it for their own shell, at least.  There is also [Win32::ShellQuote](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::ShellQuote)

Comment: @elizabethfcompton  Updated the answer with a specific detail (actual command, tested). If for some reason it doesn't work please let me know what systems are involved.  (Works in my tests on Linux.)

Answer (score -1):

I am using a shortened example here

```
system("ssh localhost 'awk '{print $2,$1}' file.txt'")

system() sees:
    ssh localhost 'awk '{print $2,$1}' file.txt'
local shell expands:
    ssh
    localhost
    awk 
    {print
    $2,$1}
     file.txt
local shell replaces $1 and $2 (positional args) with empty strings:
    ssh
    localhost
    awk 
    {print
    ,}
     file.txt
ssh executes:
    ssh localhost awk {print ,} file.txt
remote shell gets:
    awk
    {print
    ,}
    file.txt
```

So the remote shell runs `awk` with `{print` as its program argument, resulting in the described error. To prevent this, the invocation of `system()` can be changed to;

```
system("ssh localhost \"awk '{print \$2,\$1}' file.txt\"")

system() sees:
    ssh localhost "awk '{print \$2,\$1}' file.txt"
local shell expands:
    ssh
    localhost
    awk '{print \$2,\$1}' file.txt
ssh executes
    ssh localhost awk '{print \$2,\$1}' file.txt
remote shell gets
    awk
    {print \$2,\$1}
    file.txt
remote shell expands \ escapes
    awk
    {print $2,$1}
    file.txt
```

Remote awk now gets `{print $2,$1}` as its program argument, and executes successfully.

Comment: Nice idea to break it up like that  (I am not sure about every detail of the analysis but it's surely useful) but the final command doesn't actually work for me; I need `\\\$1` and `\\\$2`